# Can someone explain this Jquery

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ((screen.width >= 1024) && (screen.height >= 768)) {
        alert('Screen size: 1024x768 or larger');
        $("link[rel=stylesheet]:not(:first)").attr({
            href: "style2.css"
        });
    } else {
        alert('Screen size: less than 1024x768, 800x600 maybe?');
        $("link[rel=stylesheet]:not(:first)").attr({
            href: "style1.css"
        });
    }
});
```

I'm not getting this part: `$("link[rel=stylesheet]:not(:first)").attr`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It selects all `link` tags, that have an attribute named `rel`, whose value is `stylesheet`, and that is not the first one of the tags. For example, if you had:

```
<link rel="icon" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style3.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style4.css" />
```

The selector would pick the last two `link` tags. Why? Because it *excludes* the first one, since the value of the `rel` attribute is not `stylesheet`, but `icon`; and *excludes* the second one, because it's the *first* of all the `link`s that have the attribute `rel="stylesheet"`, and `not(:first)` filters this one out.

Comment: Thank you for the fast replay and help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("link[rel=stylesheet]:not(:first)").attr({href : "style1.css"});
```

break it down into its parts. The selector in this case will match any `<link>` element, that has a `rel` attribute that equals `stylesheet`, but it is `:not` the (`:first`) one it finds. When found. The Jquery attaches an `href` attribute that equals the stylesheet for the browser window size... *breathe*

Answer (score 1):

**link[rel=stylesheet]** will select all of the  tags with attribute **rel="stylesheet"**

and **:not(:first)** will filter out the first one

Answer (score 1):

Those are CSS selectors. In this particular example, all of the link tags whose rel values is "stylesheet" are being selected but the first one encountered will be omitted.

The following are pretty good for getting to grips with selectors:

W3Schools reference: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Nettuts article: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/